# What are Unicoins?

Tags: support, unicoins

I noticed today, on the right of the main page, this:

[image]

What are Unicoins? What are they used for? Is there a Pegasus-variant, perhaps with Rainbow-colourings?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Uni- *corns* are defined well by wikipedia:

> The unicorn is a legendary animal that has been described since antiquity as a beast with a large, pointed, spiraling horn projecting from its forehead. The unicorn was depicted in ancient seals of the Indus Valley Civilization and was mentioned by the ancient Greeks in accounts of natural history by various writers, including Ctesias, Strabo, Pliny the Younger, and Aelian. The Bible also describes an animal, the re'em, which some translations have rendered with the word unicorn

Here is a picture of a Unicorn, for reference:

[image]

Uni- *coins* are a new currency to be used on Stack Overflow. You will be able to exchange money for rep and vice-versa.

Comment: I still don't understand why the show is called My Little Pony if it's about unicorns.

Comment: @Sterno Unicorns are a type of pony, along with pegasus ponies and earth ponies. Perhaps next time you should watch the show instead of complaining, jeez.

Comment: I just wanted to make sure it was scientifically accurate before spending time watching it.

Comment: There, now we have a unicorn, as depicted in traditional mythology, with cloven hooves &c. and not just horses with horns stuck to them

Comment: [@PrivatePansy](http://media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m81fwhM1pa1qc5lie.png)

Comment: hmmm I bought a multiply rep power-up but I do not seem to have unlocked any privelages is it just for you to view?

Comment: @davidtoh it only appears for you, yes. Other people will see things for what they truly are.

Comment: **cough*aprilcorns*cough**